# Creating Video Maker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I have a application which allow user to pick multiple image from device add text and make a fresh final image using **RepaintBoundry** Widget which save the final image but now i want to add some more features like user can pick multiple videos and it will save video to device i have made full video editor but my problem is in saving that video which user created. If you want any code then you can ask in comments.